# select table from access database and insert to sql multiple table on c #

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, ms-access

I have an access database includes many table. And I have a sql server database with no data.  I want to select from access and insert to sql database. 
but these are not table to table.  Select from a table but insert multiple tables to sql database side.  how can I do that?

for example;

```
select customer_id, cst_name, workorder_id 
    from (customer inner join workorder on workorder.cst_id=customer.customer_id);
```

this string from access side.

```
insert into WorkPerson (person_id, workorder_id) 
         values (customer_id, workorder_id);
```

and this string from sql side.

Two databases have primary keys and  foreign keys  especially. how can I insert without lose data and keys?

**Edit :**  Access db tables and columns  ***is not*** same with Sql Server db tables and columns.

Comment: Is this a one-off transfer?  Or are you trying to synchronise the two data stores?

Comment: Use `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON` to insert primary keys into identity columns and keep relationships working.

Comment: yes  this is a one-off transfer.

Answer (score 0):

Select data from access database and store in a data table in then you can use SQL bulk copy, table type or XML to store data into SQL database.

Comment: But access table's colums  is not same  sql table columns. So I think I can't use this way ...